# add STL file to a QT Widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I'm trying to create a viewer for STL files with QT5.10 and c++. I suceeded to view the file in a `QWindow` but I didn't find how to view it in a `QWidget`. This is what i want to do [Qt Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyCKH.png).

This is the code for viewing it in a `QWindow`:

```
Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow view;

Qt3DCore::QEntity *rootEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity;
Qt3DCore::QEntity *flyingwedge = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);

Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial *material = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial();
material->setDiffuse(QColor(200, 200, 200));

Qt3DRender::QMesh *stlObjectMesh = new Qt3DRender::QMesh;
stlObjectMesh->setMeshName("Onshape");
stlObjectMesh->setSource(data);
flyingwedge->addComponent(stlObjectMesh);
flyingwedge->addComponent(material);

Qt3DRender::QCamera *camera = view.camera();
camera->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(1000.0f, 16.0f/9.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
camera->setPosition(QVector3D(-500, -100, 40.0f));
camera->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0));

Qt3DCore::QEntity *lightEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
Qt3DRender::QPointLight *light = new Qt3DRender::QPointLight(lightEntity);
light->setColor("white");
light->setIntensity(0.8f);
lightEntity->addComponent(light);

Qt3DCore::QTransform *lightTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(lightEntity);
lightTransform->setTranslation(QVector3D(60, 0, 40.0f));
lightEntity->addComponent(lightTransform);

Qt3DExtras::QOrbitCameraController *camController = new Qt3DExtras::QOrbitCameraController(rootEntity);

camController->setCamera(camera);
camController->setLinearSpeed( 5000.0f );
camController->setLookSpeed( 1000.0f );
view.setRootEntity(rootEntity);
view.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a container for your 3D window. This container is a `QWidget` which you can then embed in the rest of your layout.

```
QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(3DWindow);
widgetLayout->addWidget(container);
```

Of course you have to omit `view.show();` on the 3D window but call this on your main window.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer,i got the idea of embedding the window in the widget but i wonder if i need to create a Qt3DWindow object and then add it to the mainwindow class ? i'm using the QT designer actualy it's somehow confusing for me.

Comment: You simply create your layout like you're used to in the Qt Designer and add e.g. an empty frame where you want to have to 3D Window later. Then, in the construcotr code of the main window (or if you need the 3D Window in your custom QWidget, then in the code of the QWidget) you create the 3D Window just like you posted above but do not call view.show(). Instead, add the container of the 3D window to the layout of the empty frame.

Comment: Thank you verry much,this was realy helpfull it worked perfectly !

Comment: Can you please share  your code. I have copied and pasted exact code in my qt project. Imported stl file using QURL and assigned to data. but nothing is showing. What am I doing wrong ?